# Laravel - How to navigate to table content in accordance with a specific page number?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have a table nested inside a directive `@section('content')` of `customers.blade.php` view extended from another view called `home.blade.php` like this `@extends('home',[$pageNumber])`. Each table view has 20 rows of data fetched from SQL database.
The table footer has two navigation buttons:

```
<button
    class="navigation-button"
    id="navigation-button--previous"
    onclick="decrementPageNumber()"
> < </button>
Page: {{$pageNumber}}
<button
    class="navigation-button"
    id="navigation-button--next"
    onclick="incrementPageNumber()"
> > </button>
```

What I want is to navigate to view with respect to `$pageNumber` whenever clicking the `>` button so I wrote a function called `incrementPageNumber()` to send a message to the PHP part of the file:

```
function incrementPageNumber()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var requestMessage = "next";
    request.open('GET',"http://127.0.0.1:8080/customers",true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(requestMessage);
    console.log("Request successfully!");

    var request = require('axios');
    request.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/customers",requestMessage);
}
```

I tried using both XMLHTTPRequest and axios but none of them worked.

```
<?php
    $pageNumber = 1;
?>
```

Everything is inside the file `customers.blade.php`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Laravel has [pagination built in](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination), which includes page links. Have you tried using that?

Comment: @aynber I have no idea. Please give me some clues!